# How do I set a date range for 2 recurring days each week over a 2 or 3 month period in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2005

I'm working in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and need to do an analysis of players who qualify for our 50+ tournament on Tuesdays --> To qualify, they need to get 5+ points on Mon or Tues that week before 2pm, and the points are not cumulative (must get a min of 5 on Mon or on Tues before 2pm). The code I am using is below but so far only contains a date range for a specific Monday and Tuesday. I need all Mondays and Tuesdays over a 2 month timeframe. I am new to this (kinda thrown in my lap as an extra duty so I am having to learn on the fly)...

So far, as I stated, I have been able to succeed on my own in getting all the information I need but it is only specific to 1 week. Everything I have found online so far has been more confusing than I can explain and nobody has referenced the code I provided, instead giving me completely new code that I cannot use...

```
SELECT     
     dbo.CombinedPts.Account, dbo.CombinedPts.FirstName, 
     dbo.CombinedPts.LastName, 
     ISNULL(dbo.CombinedPts.EGSPts, 0) AS EGS, 
     ISNULL(dbo.CombinedPts.IRPts, 0) AS IR, 
     DATENAME(dw, dbo.CombinedPts.Date) AS WkDay, 
     DATEDIFF(YY, dbo.PlayerMaster.Birthdate, {fn current_date()}) - CASE WHEN   (MONTH(dbo.PlayerMaster.Birthdate)=MONTH({fn current_date()}) AND DAY(dbo.PlayerMaster.Birthdate) > DAY({fn current_date()}) OR MONTH (dbo.PlayerMaster.Birthdate) > MONTH ({fn current_date()}))  THEN 1   ELSE 0   END   AS Age
FROM       
     dbo.CombinedPts, dbo.PlayerMaster 
WHERE      
     (DATEDIFF(YY, dbo.PlayerMaster.Birthdate, {fn current_date()}) >= 50) 
     AND (dbo.CombinedPts.EGSPts >= 5 OR dbo.CombinedPts.IRPts >= 5) 
     AND (dbo.CombinedPts.Account = dbo.PlayerMaster.Account) 
     AND (Date BETWEEN '10/11/2010 00:00:00' AND '10/11/2010 13:59:59' OR Date BETWEEN '10/12/2010 00:00:00' AND '10/12/2010 13:59:59') 
     AND (DATEPART(dw, dbo.CombinedPts.Date) = 2 OR DATEPART(dw, dbo.CombinedPts.Date) = 3)
GROUP BY   
     dbo.CombinedPts.Account, 
     dbo.CombinedPts.FirstName, 
     dbo.CombinedPts.LastName, 
     DATENAME(dw, dbo.CombinedPts.Date), 
     dbo.CombinedPts.EGSPts, 
     dbo.CombinedPts.IRPts, 
     dbo.PlayerMaster.Birthdate
ORDER BY
     dbo.CombinedPts.Account
```

As a side note, in our SQL Server 2005, I do not have permissions to create subqueries (I have become an avid user of UNION ALL --> which has proved useless in the query so far) nor do I have permission to generate tables, so everything I do has to be in one query... And thus far, all help that has made some sense has been using tables and subqueries.

Comment: What column can you join dbo.CombinedPts, dbo.PlayerMaster on?  Are you running this within Management Studio?

Comment: I was unaware that subqueries were something that could be denied by permissions...are you sure that it was a permissions error and not a syntax error in your subquery?

Comment: We run it on a network and it is somehow set so that only one person (our IT director) can edit anything ie I cannot save anything in SQL Server 2005 so cannot also create subqueries as it won't let me link them becasue they are unsaved. He keeps telling me he will fix it so I can use the view and design (it won't let me do that either) and so I can save table and subqueries but not actually make changes to the databases, but that has yet to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little different structure, but mostly the same.  I used aliases instead of full references.  It's also untested, but parses cleanly.

The `AND DATEDIFF(m,cp.Date,GETDATE()) < 2` gives you the 2 month window.

EDIT - Added the clauses for the Day and Time.  `AND (DATEPART(dw, cp.Date) in (2,3) AND DATEPART(hh,cp.Date) > 14)` gives you only Monday and Tuesday after 2:00pm (1400 hours)

```
SELECT cp.Account
, cp.FirstName
, cp.LastName
, ISNULL(cp.EGSPts,0) AS EGS
, ISNULL(cp.IRPts,0) AS IR
, DATENAME(dw, cp.Date) AS WkDay
, DATEDIFF(YY, pm.Birthdate, GETDATE()) 
        - CASE WHEN (MONTH(pm.Birthdate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
        AND DAY(pm.Birthdate) > DAY(GETDATE()) 
        OR MONTH (pm.Birthdate) > MONTH (GETDATE()) )
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END AS Age

FROM dbo.CombinedPts cp
join dbo.PlayerMaster pm on cp.Account = pm.Account

WHERE DATEDIFF(YY, pm.Birthdate, GETDATE()) >= 50
 AND (cp.EGSPts >= 5 OR cp.IRPts >= 5)
 AND (DATEPART(dw, cp.Date) in (2,3) AND DATEPART(hh,cp.Date) > 14)
 AND DATEDIFF(m,cp.Date,GETDATE()) < 2

GROUP BY cp.Account
, cp.FirstName
, cp.LastName
, DATENAME(dw, cp.Date)
, cp.EGSPts
, cp.IRPts
, pm.Birthdate

ORDER BY cp.Account
```

Comment: It works and is giving correct parameters for the most part. ^^ Question, how do I specify the window of 00:00:00 on monday to 13:59:59 on monday (same for tuesdays)?

Comment: Oh, you answered my question before I asked it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want to achieve.

I think you want something like this:

```
select *
  from CombinedPts
 where CombinedPts.Date > start_of_contest
  and CombinedPts.Date < end_of_contest
  and ( datepart( dw, CombinedPts.Date ) = 2 or datepart( h, CombinedPts.Date ) < 14 )
  and ( datepart( dw, CombinedPts.Date ) = 3 or datepart( h, CombinedPts.Date ) < 14 )
 having sum( CombinedPts.EGSPts ) >= 5
```

Datepart is used here to ensure it's on the correct day and time.

Comment: I'm not 100% either... this is only the 2nd analysis they have had me do...That looks nicer than what I have seen, but there are more parameters than what are shown such as age >= 50 (found only in PlayerMaster), EGS >=5, IR >= 5, and only Mon or Tues before 2pm (the rest found in CombinedPts).